# Nested controllers Form_with Devise Error

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

So, I have a RailsApp and I decided to do a nested controller to my users called backoffice.

**My routes to index are working fine**, but when I try to edit or create a user, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Backoffice::Users#new
undefined method `users_path' for #<#
<Class:0x007efc6d4fd1c8>:0x007efc6cd38708>
Did you mean?  user_session_path
```

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :advertises
  resources :categories

  devise_for :users

  namespace :backoffice do
    resources :users, except: [:show]
  end
end
```

I'm using Rails 5.1.4, so the 'form_tag' and 'form_for' are replaced for the 'form_with'

Here are my _form.html.erb where are my problem:

```
<%= form_with(model: user, root: true) do |form| %>
```

The structure of the controller is

```
class Backoffice::UsersController < BackofficeController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :pundit_user
....
```

Could the problem be with devise? Or it's just a nested controller error?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably move the `devise_for` call into the `:backoffice` namespace as that is where the users resource is located.

If you run `rails routes` in the command line you will see the problem. Devise is trying to call `users_path` but that doesn't exist, what exists is `backoffice_users_path`

Comment: I've thought that too, but it was not, I moved it, inside backoffice, above and under of resources.